# Не правильно отображается Background

Tags: html5, css3

Background отображается не с самого верху

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url(/img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
  background-position: top center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `padding 0;`  ??

Answer (score 1):

Вроде все нормально работает

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(https://yandex.kz/images/today?size=1920x1080) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```